# mysql selecting rows randomly with percent conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a project for a lottery game, so we have to do a random preselections.

This is the table stucture:

```
-------------------------------------------
|id| gamer_name | gender | city |  job    |
-------------------------------------------
|1 | name1      | Male   | city1| job 1   |
-------------------------------------------
|2 | name2      | female | city2| job2    |
-------------------------------------------
```

I have to write a query on the table to get 200 rows at random, with the following conditions:

- 50% male (100 rows) and 50% female (100 rows)
- 10% from 200 rows are from city1
- 50% from 200 rows are from city2
- 40% from 200 rows are from (other cities)

What query can fit these results?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base to start with.

If you want to select a random number of items, use something along the lines of

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

So if you want half of the people to be male, limit it to 100

However, I do not see how your percentages add up... you are trying to select 160%?

Answer (score 0):

Using Mysql only.

```
Create table Male like YOUR_TABLE;
INSERT INTO Male SELECT * from (SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE gender="Male");
Create table Result like YOUR_TABLE;
INSERT INTO Result (SELECT * from Male where city not in ('city1', 'city2') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 40);
INSERT INTO Result (SELECT * from Male where city='city1' and id not in (SELECT id from Result) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10);
INSERT INTO Result (SELECT * from Male where city='city2' and id not in (SELECT id from Result) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50);
```

You might need to tweak the queries a little bit.